# Android service closed even with startForeground()

Tags: java, android, notifications

So I need a service for my app, but I need it to keep running all the time until the user press the end Button in the app. It goes like this : The user press start, my service start (starting a notification btw), then 2-3h or more later the user has to click on the notification which get him back to the app where he can press the "End" button and end the service. I call this a Start-End cycle for simplicity purposes.
My user will use many Start-End cycles a day, but the problem is my notification goes away after some time when the phone his lock.
I've already been able to put the notification and service thanks to Stackoverflow so I hope you have a solution for this too :)!

Here is my main activity :

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     checkEnabled();
    mTimeListenerD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {  //Button to set the Start time
            setDebutTime();
            checkEnabled();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent start=new Intent(MainActivity.this,TimeService.class);
                    start.putExtra("StopSig",false);
                    start.putExtra("Temps_travail",mTempsTravail); //Envoi Long
                    start.putExtra("mSmallest",mSmallest); //Envoi Long
                    start.putExtra("file_src",src); //Envoi String
                    start.putExtra("file_dst",dst); //Envoi String
                    start.putExtra("Debut",sDebut); //Envoi String
                    start.putExtra("Fin",sFin); //Envoi String
                    start.putExtra("Name",sName);//Envoi String
                    start.putExtra("String_travail",sTempsTravail); //Envoi String
                    start.putExtra("Smallest",sSmallest);//Envoi String*/
                    startService(start);
                }
            }).start();

        }
    });
    mTimeListenerF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { //Button to set the End Time
            setFinTime();
            checkEnabled();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent end = new Intent(MainActivity.this,TimeService.class);
                    end.putExtra("StopSig",true);
                    end.putExtra("TimeF",mTimeF);
                    end.putExtra("Temps_travail",mTempsTravail); //Envoi Long
                    end.putExtra("mSmallest",mSmallest); //Envoi Long
                    end.putExtra("file_src",src); //Envoi String
                    end.putExtra("file_dst",dst); //Envoi String
                    end.putExtra("Debut",sDebut); //Envoi String
                    end.putExtra("Fin",sFin); //Envoi String
                    end.putExtra("Name",sName);//Envoi String
                    end.putExtra("String_travail",sTempsTravail); //Envoi String
                    end.putExtra("Smallest",sSmallest);
                    // startService(end);
                    stopService(end);
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
    mMail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendMail();
        }
    }); //Send data by mail
```

Here is the service i use, with the method that show the notification:

```
    public class TimeService extends Service {
    @Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Service onCreate");
    mContext=TimeService.this;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Service onStartCommand");
    Toast.makeText(this,"TimeServiceStarted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    stopSig=intent.getBooleanExtra("StopSig",false); //Receiving Boolean
    setDebutTime();
   setNotification();
    //Stop service once it finishes its task
    //stopSelf();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Service onBind");
    TSTempsTravail=arg0.getLongExtra("Temps_travail",TSTempsTravail); //Receiving Long
    TSSmallest=arg0.getLongExtra("mSmallest",TSSmallest);//Receiving Long
    sName=arg0.getStringExtra("Name");//Receiving String
    sDebut= arg0.getStringExtra("Debut");//Receiving String
    sFin= arg0.getStringExtra("Fin");//Receiving String
    sTempsTravail= arg0.getStringExtra("String_travail");//Receiving String
    sSmallest=arg0.getStringExtra("Smallest");//Receiving String
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopSig=true;
    setFinTime();
   // getName();
    getHeureSupp(TimeD,TimeF);
    Clock();
    writeToFile(sDebut,sFin,sName,sTempsTravail);
    try {
        copyFile(src,dst);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //sendMail();
    Log.i(TAG, "Service onDestroy");
    //Toast.makeText(this,"Service stopped",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
        public void setNotification() {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    /*notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);*/
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 15, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.logo);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("myTitle")
            .setTicker("myTicker")
            .setContentText("myText")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_small)
            .setLargeIcon(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, 128, 128, false))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setOngoing(true);
    startForeground(15, notification.build());
}
```

And finally here is the Manifest if that can be useful in anyway :

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.benjii.myapp">
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
      <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo_small"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name=".TimeService"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo_small"
        android:label="@string/service">
    </service>
</application>
   </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Application components (services, activities, etc) always run in main thread, no matter what thread they are started from. Consider starting thread in your Service instead, or use an IntentService.